# Getting unmarshal invalid value error, but the same data is okay in unit test

Tags: go

the below piece of code:

```
func (ce *CloudEvent) ReadSettlement() (*pbv1b1.Settlement, error) {
    event := validSettlementEvent[ce.CeType]
    fmt.Println("Before unmarshal")
    fmt.Println(ce.Message.Message.Data)
    if err := ce.unmarshal(ce.Message.Message.Data, event); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unmarshal Error")
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("After unmarshal")
    return event.GetData(), nil
}
```

Seems like it is behaving differently in unit test and in postman test. I used the same set of data, unit test goes into After unmarshal branch without getting any unmarshal error. But the postman test goes into Unmarshal error branch. The error is invalid value.

In line fmt.Println(ce.Message.Message.Data), it prints out some unreadable code looks like: [... 74 6 8 128 255 211 171 6 80 1]. But I checked in both scenarios the numbers seem to be identical too.

I checked the postman setting, it seems to be okay to me too:
[image]

I haven't added any header in this request.

Does anyone know why it behaves so differently?

Comment: the array of numbers is typical of calling `fmt.Println(v)` when `v` has type `[]byte` (and not `string`). see https://go.dev/play/p/jAHa28vaOmE for an illustration. Check the type that is defined for your `.Data` field

Comment: "invalid value" does not look like an error message from the JSON package.  What is the exact error string for the error?  Use `fmt.Println("Unmarshal Error", err)` to get it.

Comment: my understanding is that `json.Unmarshal(...)` works correctly (e.g: it doesn't return an error value, you do not see a `Unmarshal error` message in your ouput), your issue is more about understanding how to manipulate or inspect the resulting data structure, am I correct ?

Comment: Where does the CloudEvent come from? Some implementations do a base64 encoding of the payload...

Comment: @CeriseLimón I think the error is happening at unmarshal, when I do println(err) before fmt.Println("Unmarshal Error"), I got this: 
proto: syntax error (line 2:1): invalid value ?

Comment: @LeGEC I feel like it is json.Unmarshall getting the error, when printing the error out it says: proto: syntax error (line 2:1): invalid value ?